# Set position of outerBelowCircle CAShapeLayer in the center of View

Tags: swift, view, cashapelayer

I make a circle by using CAShapeLayer, and I want to set the center of it, in the center of the view. But the circle will be created exactly below the center line (see the screenshot), could anyone help me on this?

```
let circle = CAShapeLayer()
view.layer.addSublayer(circle)
circle.position = view.center


    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    circle.path = circularPath.cgPath
```

I also change the way that for setting it in the center, but It doesn't work

```
circle.position = CGPoint(x: view.layer.bounds.midX, y: view.layer.bounds.midY)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem from the link that you provided.

Comment: It is because you are setting the view's centre as the start position angle zero of the circle. Possibly you can achieve this by changing the position by adjusting with some offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following method according to your screenshot this method will resolve your issue.

```
func showCircle() {

    let view = UIView()
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    view.layer.addSublayer(circle)
    let positionX = view.center.x
    let positionY = view.center.y - 100 // your circle radius
    circle.position = CGPoint(x: positionX, y:  positionY)


    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    circle.path = circularPath.cgPath
}
```

I haven't tested the code. Please verify it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.